# Dynamically setting unknown readonly property at runtime in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm building a class that sets properties of a subclass dynamically at runtime from a plist, that works like this:

#### Example

[image: Property list editor screenshot]

You declare your properties in a subclass to match the names of keys:

```
#import "PlistModel.h"

@interface CustomModel : PlistModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * StringPropertyKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate * DatePropertyKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * ArrayPropertyKey;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary * DictionaryPropertyKey;

@property int IntPropertyKey;
@property BOOL BoolPropertyKey;
@property float FloatPropertyKey;

@end
```

That's it! The values are automatically populated at runtime without any additional code:

```
[CustomModel plistNamed:@"CustomModel" inBackgroundWithBlock:^(PlistModel *plistModel) {

    CustomModel * customModel = (CustomModel *)plistModel;

    NSLog(@"StringProperty: %@", customModel.StringPropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"DateProperty: %@", customModel.DatePropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"ArrayProperty: %@", customModel.ArrayPropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"DictionaryProperty: %@", customModel.DictionaryPropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"IntProperty: %i", customModel.IntPropertyKey);
    NSLog(@"BoolProperty: %@", customModel.BoolPropertyKey ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    NSLog(@"FloatProperty: %f", customModel.FloatPropertyKey);

}];
```

#### Problem

I set the properties at runtime by generating a selector and calling it with the value I want to set like this:

```
SEL propertySetterSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"set<#PropertyName#>:"); 
void (*func)(id, SEL, id) = (void *)imp;
func(self, propertySetterSelector, objectToSet);
```

But, if for some reason a property is `readonly` the selector won't exist, so I'm looking for an alternative.  I've found a way to identify that a property is readonly here:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getPropertyNames {

    // Prepare Package
    NSMutableArray * propertyNames = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Fetch Properties
    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);

    // Parse Out Properties
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        const char * name = property_getName(property);
        // NSLog(@"Name: %s", name);
        const char * attributes = property_getAttributes(property);
        NSLog(@"Attributes: %s", attributes);
        NSString * attributeString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:attributes];
        NSArray * attributesArray = [attributeString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        if ([attributesArray containsObject:@"R"]) {
            // is ReadOnly
            NSLog(@"%s is read only", name);

            // -- CAN I SET THE PROPERTY HERE? -- //
            // property = @"Set"; ?
        }
        // Add to our array
        [propertyNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]];
    }

    // Free our properties
    free(properties);

    // Send it off
    return propertyNames;
}
```

Perhaps if there's a way to set a `objc_property_t` ref directly.

#### Update

Through comments, I've realized there's some confusion.  I think the core of my question is whether or not its possible to set an unknown property at runtime another way besides calling the selector like I'm doing.

#### Resources

Full Project: [Here!](https://github.com/LoganWright/PlistModel)

CodeReview Post that prompted this question: [Here!](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/48723/38794)

#### SetValue: forKey: Update

I have a readonly property:

```
@property (readonly) NSString * readOnlyProperty;
```

I declare this in the class:

```
+ (BOOL) accessInstanceVariablesDirectly {
    return YES;
}
```

I call this:

```
[self setValue:@"HI" forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]];

// -- OR -- // 

[self setValue:@"HI" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name]]];
```

Either way, value is still null.

Comment: Keep in mind that a property is not necessarily just an instance variable.  The property getter and setter are real methods that can do anything: read and write a database, compute the property value based on other data, return a random number, or set your computer on fire.  Now, are you sure that if the property is marked `readonly` you want to try to set it anyway?  Maybe it's `readonly` because you're not supposed to try setting it.

Comment: @Robmayoff - For this particular class, I can't imagine someone would set a readonly property, and I wouldn't recommend it. Also, for this class, I you have to use the autosynthesized getters setters.  Mostly, this question is based on my own curiosity.  Sometimes I just want to see if I can do it.

Comment: Are you just trying to determine if the selector exists?  why not just call respondsToSelector for the object and selector?  If the selector doesn't exist you will know and just avoid calling it.

Comment: @dboals - I do call that in the class, and it works fine.  I think I'm mostly wondering if it's possible to set a property another way besides calling the selector like I'm doing.  Maybe I should rephrase the question.

Comment: Aside: you know that key-value coding is the normal way to achieve setting a named property? i.e. `setValue:forKey:` rather than tying to compose the setter name and do a dynamic lookup on that method. E.g. it's how NIBs are loaded (though it's also how about a million other things are done).

Comment: But, no, if a class intends a property to be `readonly` that means it doesn't intend other people to set it. So it doesn't expose a means to set it. That's what the words 'read only' mean.

Comment: @Tommy - That's what I was afraid of, should I delete this question?

Comment: I wouldn't as someone smarter than me may come up with a hack around. It's all accessible memory that you own and C allows arbitrary pointer dereferencing, I just can't think of a way to get the offset of an instance variable by name from outside if the class doesn't intend you to.

Comment: Since CustomModel is going to be created by some other person in XCode, you could just throw an exception saying something along the lines of "for a readonly property, also declare it as readwrite in the private @interface" -- not sure you have to delve into the runtime to solve an issue that can be solved trivially by your users.

Comment: @stevesliva - I agree, this is definitely a very rare case, and I think that's how I'll implement the final class.  I still want to try and figure it out though, just because at this point its become a matter of trying to do it just for fun! :)

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE

You can try using `setValue:forKey:` for a `readonly` property, **if** the target class has defines the class method `accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` to return `YES` and if the property stores its value in a conventionally-named instance variable.  See [“ Default Search Pattern for setValue:forKey:” in the *Key-Value Coding Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-CJBBBFFA).  KVC will unbox a primitive value if necessary.

### ORIGINAL

It is not possible to set a *property* except by calling the property's setter, because a property is *defined* as a getter and optionally a setter.  You can use the `setValue:forKey:` method of Key-Value Coding (KVC), and that's simpler and more reliably than constructing the setter name yourself, but under the covers that still calls the property's setter.

It is possible to set an *instance variable* using the Objective-C runtime.  Look at the [`class_getInstanceVariable`, `object_setInstanceVariable`, and `object_setIvar` methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html).

You can guess that a property's value is stored in an instance variable whose name is the property named with an `_` prefix.  However, this is only a convention.  The compiler uses the convention for auto-synthesized properties, but the compiler does not enforce the convention.

Comment: Can I assign 'int' and 'bool' types using `object_setIvar`?

Comment: It looks like you have to use `object_setInstanceVariable` for primitive types.  You can [download the Objective-C runtime source code](http://opensource.apple.com/release/os-x-109/) if you need to really understand how it works.  It's the “objc4” package.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, this is a lot of really useful stuff that I had overlooked.

Comment: `setValue:forKey:` will set the underlying ivar if there's no setter, won't it?

Comment: @JesseRusak Good call.  It will, if the class defines `accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` to return `YES`.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing it as you suggest, can you see if I'm missing a step in my latest update?

Comment: _+1_ Key-Value Coding works for readonly properties, as long as it has `ivar` or `_ivar` (doing this is probably wrong, though). It also works for primitive types like `int`, but you have to wrap it in `NSNumber`. Any other way of doing this manually is wasting of time.